# C : redefinition of typedef in different inmodifiable modules

Tags: c, typedef, redefinition

I'm using external modules in my code, and I have 2 differents typedef in two modules, and, obviously the 2 definitions are differents. One is typedef int BOOLEAN the other one is typedef unsigned char BOOLEAN.

So, when I try to compile, I got the "redefinition" error...

The simple solution is to "kill" one of these typedef.
But... that's why I ask here, I should not modify these two modules as standard modules used in many other systems...
So I was asking if it is possible to "dynamically" kill one of these typedef, let say during precompilation?

for example,is there a solution like for #define, you can use #undef (which does not work here as it is not a #define action...)

Comment: Add an `#ifndef` before one of the definitions as you please?

Comment: You wouldn't get a redefinition error unless this is in *headers* and both of them are included in the same C file. Please post a [mcve]. Or at least the **full error message**

Comment: You should kill both. C has a proper Boolean type, `bool` (or `_Bool`) and in 2018, you should never use anything else than this.

Comment: Simply don't use crap libraries that have not been maintained during the last 19 years (since year 1999).

Comment: You must design your application to never include both typedef into a single translation unit. If necessary, to can write wrappers to hide the includes from one ot the modules.

Comment: You cannot dynamically 'kill' the modules, since that is done at the compilation time.